# Why do we promote Ubiquitous Computing when there are problems out there that cannot be solved computationally?

Tags: np-complete, computation-models

According to Alan Turing, there are 2 types of problems i.e. NP Complete and non-NP Complete, then
why do we promote Ubiquitous Computing and introducing sensors and embedded systems into our daily lives to solve problems? Would it be correct to claim that Ubiquitous Computing is a misnomer or Turing's theory of NP-completeness is invalid and there is always an algorithm for a problem under consideration.

Comment: The theory of NP-completeness is due to Cook, Karp and Levin.

Comment: Ubiquitous computing is about enhancing more devices with computational power. It has nothing to do with computability or NP-completeness. Your cell phone functions as a mobile GPS device — what does this have to do with NP-completeness?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for cell phone as a mobile GPS device, the algorithm does exist to compute the location(longitude and latitude). And since the algorithm exists, therefore the devices with computational power makes sense to be in place. But what about problems for which algorithm does not exist at all?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ubiquitous computing.